# angular templating in ionic documentation. What should id attribute be on script tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm confused by the conflicting templating examples in the ionic docs. Just what value am I supposed to give the "id" attribute on the script tag for the template? The examples below will show the two different formats the ionic docs provide. 
 link here for reference:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

code sample 1

if you look at the docs you'll see the code in the simulator (html tab) has a script id that looks like this :

```
<script **id="templates/tabs.html"** type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">
       //tab content
      </ion-tabs>
    </script>
```

It appears to be a path.

but on the main page the script id example looks like this:

```
<script **id="home"** type="text/ng-template">
   <!-- ion directives -->

</script>
```

why the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `script` with `type="text/ng-template"` is another way to introduce template in Angular. What it does is, it takes down the `template` as `string` & put it inside `$templateCache` service with `key` whatever you specified inside `id` option.

So `id` option is nothing but what should be your `templateUrl`. So when you do either `ng-include="'templates/tabs.html'"` or `$templateCache.get('templates/tabs.html')` or `$templateRequest('templates/tabs.html')` will directly gives you template from `$templateCache`.

> why the difference?

Apparently there is no difference between them technically. Though I'd recommend you to use `templates/path/templateName.html` convention while defining inline template. Even all the angular libraries do follow the same convention like `ui-bootstrap`, `ui-select`, etc.